# grep for "fixme" as well as "fix me" and then cat results in single file

Tags: linux, search, grep, cat

I am trying to achieve two things here:

1. grep for fixme as well as fix me.
2. the results of the above grep should be in a single file
3. Count number of fixme (including fix me)

for step 1 I tried 
`grep -ir fixme|fix me" src/*`
but it didn't work.

is there a way it can be done in the same grep command?

for step 2 my idea was `grep -ir fixme|fix me" src/* > fixme.log` if the first step works.

for 3 can it be done using single grep command something which essentially works like this:

`grep -ir "fixme|fix me" src/* | wc -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a POSIX ERE regex like

```
grep -E -ir 'fix ?me' src/*
```

The `fix ?me` regex matches `fix`, then an optional space, and then `me`. The same can be written with POSIX BRE pattern:

```
grep -ir 'fix \{0,1\}me' src/*
```

where  `\{0,1\}` means *1 or 0 spaces*.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E -ir "fixme|fix me" src/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer but this works:
`grep -ir "FIXME" src/* > f1.log ; grep -ir "FIX ME" src/* > f2.log ; cat f1.log f2.log > fixme.log`

Comment: I would also like to point out that: `grep -E -ir "fixme|fix me" src/* | wc -l` is NOT necessarily equal to `grep -ir "FIXME" src/* > f1.log ; grep -ir "FIX ME" src/* > f2.log ; cat f1.log f2.log > fixme.log; wc -l fixme.log`.